# how to get my app user details if user with in beacon area

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I want to make an app using beacons like displaying other users to current user with in beacon range,Is it possible thing ?i have tried to connecting android app with beacon currently able to get beacon information with in android app but next what to do.Some one guide me how to proceed for maintaining users and other details here using mobile back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a web server implementation to store the list of users that currently are in that certain area the beacon indicates. When a device with your app gets in a certain range, it needs to send the user information to your server so the server can store the information. When the device exits the region your app needs to inform the server about that, so the user information gets deleted from that list.

You cannot connect to a beacon due to it being a broadcasting device and nothing more.